# Adding points to MatOfPoint2f

Tags: android, arrays, opencv

I am trying to add points to MatOfPoint2f in opencv for android, but am not sure of the most efficient method to do this. I am thinking of calling MatOfPoint2f.toArray(), then adding that to an arraylist, then adding my elements, then calling MatOfPoint2f.fromArray(). I have tried to use the MatOfPoint2f method put, but sometimes I am adding elements past the bounds of the array, so that will not work. I also tried calling the toList() method and using the add method, but the list it gives me cannot add or put elements in it. I saw the method push_back in mat, and I am sure that this will not work either, because it adds elements to lower rows, and I believe all the points are stored in the columns on row 0.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you say add points what exactly do you mean?  Do they always get added to the bottom of the matrix?  Can they go anywhere?  If you insert an element somewhere do all the elements after that need to shift over one spot?  What are the rules for inserting?  Some versions are a lot easier than others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using a linkedlist global variable, and whenever I need to add or remove points, I do it in that linkedlist, then call the method in MatOfPoint.fromList() which loads the matrix from a list. It is not pretty, but it does what I need it to.

Answer (score 0):

Just had this same problem and got (I think) a better answer. I have:

```
MatOfPoint2f allContours = new MatOfPoint2f();
MatOfPoint2f oneContour = new MatOfPoint2f();
```

Once I have a set of values in oneContour, what I am using is:

```
allContours.push_back(oneContour);
```